# How to fetch the data from the master table in model and use in another model in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

> Here is my one model name "Department"

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'dept_master';
}
```

> and the controller of the department is

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;



use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Department;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{
    public function departmentsName()
    {

        $departments = DB::table('dept_master')->orderBy('edesc','ASC')->get();
        return $departments;
    }
}
```

> and another model grievance register

```
<?php

    namespace App;
    //namespace Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


    class GrievanceRegister extends Model
    {

    }
```

> and the grievance controller is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\GrievanceRegister;
use App\Department;

class GrievanceRegisterController extends Controller
{
   public function show()
   {
  $departments = Department::orderBy('edesc','ASC')->get();
  return view('griev_reg_form', array('departments' => $departments));
}

}

   ?>
```

> and in the view file

```
 <select name="departments"> <?php foreach($departments as $result)
                {
                    ?> <option value="<?php echo $result->deptcode; ?>"><?php echo $result->edesc; ?></option>  <?php   }       ?>
                    </select>
```

> Is it a correct way to call one model data from another model and
>   controller. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You can fetch data from model in any controller. Please elaborate what you mean by: `how to fetch the data from office table and use in another controller`

Comment: i have two models and in one model i want to fetch data from office table and in another model i have to use that first model data

Comment: First of all, models are solely responsible for a particular table interaction. You dont do logics in model itself. FOr that you have controllers and middlewares. I believe you are trying to achive something in wrong way. If you can show us some code or elaborate more what do you want to achieve. Maybe someone can help.

Comment: see the edited one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure concept of model and controllers are clear to you.

I try my best to explain a bit here.

So **Model** is used to communicate with a table.

In you case, I am guessing by seeing you code is that, you have a table named: `departments` so that is why you will have a model `Department` with help of which you can save, update, delete or extract data from `departments` table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

again its better to have first alphabet capital case.

`$fillable` variable defines what fields in table are mass assignable. See [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) here for Lravel 5.4

Now I have assumed that you have `id` and `name` field in your table `departments`

Now in your controller you are referring to some table: `dept_master` which doesn't make sense.

You controller should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Department;

use App\department;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{
    public function departmentsName()
    {
        $departments = Department::orderBy('edesc','ASC')->get();
        return $departments;
    }
}
```

I dont know what you are trying to achieve with `$table` variable in your model which contains string `dept_master` and what is this table `dept_master`.

I have explained the concept of model and controller.

Have model for each and every table and access them anywhere from any controller via models. Its as simple as it is.

And as I mentioned in my answers to your previous questions. Follow snake_case plural for table names and camelCase singular with exception of first alphabet capital for model names.

Comment: dept_master is the table name which i want to use in department model

Comment: And when i got the departments name from this table and need to use these name in another model name grievancemodel

Comment: Please check the edited question and let me know it is correct way am doing

Comment: Can you explain what table `GrievanceRegister` model represents.

Comment: its grievance_register

Comment: I dont know why you cant use `Department` model in `GrievanceRegisterController` controller to retrieve all departments. Controllers are not associated with one model..any model can be used in any controller